# Stripe subscription always gives me "status: 'requires_confirmation'

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have a subscription route like this. My flow looks like this

1. User select a plan.
2. User enter card details through Stripe Card Element
3. User click Subscribe button.

As per docs,

1. I'm creating a customer.
2. Then creating a subscription for this customer.

But, my dashboard says payment incomplete and response object on creating subscriptions shows status: 'requires_confirmation'. What I am doing wrong?

```
router.post('/subscription', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const { payment_method, price_id } = req.body;

    const customer = await Stripe.customers.create({
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        payment_method: payment_method,
        description: 'New Customer',
        invoice_settings: { default_payment_method: payment_method }
    });

    try {
        const subscription = await Stripe.subscriptions.create({
            customer: customer.id,
            items: [
                {
                    price: price_id
                }
            ],
            payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
            expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent']
        });

        res.send({
            status: subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.status,
            subscriptionId: subscription.id,
            
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: { message: error.message } });
    }
});



[![Stripe dashboard][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx0zN.png
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you’re doing things a bit out of order from the way the Stripe docs suggest. In [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription?ui=elements), the subscription object is created prior to collecting the payment method. The reason your invoice isn’t automatically paid is because you are explicitly passing in a payment_behavior of default_incomplete, which tells Stripe not to pay the invoice and allows you to collect payment details client-side and confirm the payment. Since you have already collected payment details, don’t pass in a payment_bevavior of default_incomplete.